# CouchDB isn't using enough resources

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchdb server with 4GB of RAM and 2 CPU's.  Currently the database is about 20GB. Views are sitting at around 108GB pre compaction. The compaction takes 3-4 hours and in many cases the 200GB disk gets filled. I notice in top that the cpu is barely being used at around 15% and the ram is around 5% used. It seems like this shouldn't take as long if couch were using the resources allocated to it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are your buffer and checkpoint settings at? Are you using parallel db and view compaction?

Comment: I'm not using parallel db and view compaction. I'm looking in my config files and I'm not seeing a buffer and checkpoint setting.

Comment: So start by increasing the buffer size and enabling parallel compaction.

Comment: It's a local only database and I'm not replicating. What buffer are you talking about?

Comment: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/compaction.html